# How do i run assets (npm run production) on an elastic beanstalk laravel application?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, npm

I have a laravel application, running on an AWS eb instance (elastic beanstalk).I have uploded the code, and connected a database and everything works fine without any errors. But i need to compile some assets (for example tailwindcss, livewire...) so i need to run npm run production/npm run dev.
my question is how do i do so, and if i even need to.

i tried to open a .ebextensions folder. in the folder i have a file named: build_assets.config.yaml, and in that file:

```
packages:
  yum:
    nodejs: [*]

container_commands:
  01_build_assets:
    command: "npm run prod"
```

and my package.json scripts:

```
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build",
        "start": "node app.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules"
    },
```

i source bundled everything, uploded it again to eb and nothing changes, but throws no errors. the css looks all over the place because tailwindcss is not working...
i also have a npm-shrinkwrap.json file, it did not contribute.
would like to have some guidence, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It turnes out that i did not need to have that file, or anything. The jetstream documentation says how to build the application to production, and it will work fine with it.
Before publishing an application to the elastic beanstalk instance, run

> npm run build

on your application folder,

and then publish, and assets will be built already.